# 'idiomatic' Haskell type inequality

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, type-equivalence

(edited from previous question where I thought code below doesn't work)

I wish to implement a haskell function f that has a restriction such that its 2 parameters must not have the same type. I have used the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, UndecidableInstances, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies, IncoherentInstances #-}
data HTrue = HTrue
data HFalse = HFalse

class HEq x y b | x y -> b
instance (b ~ HTrue) => HEq x x b
instance (b ~ HFalse) => HEq x y b


g :: (HEq a b HFalse) => a -> b -> ()
g x y = ()
```

Now the function g only accepts a and b if they have different types. Is this the 'idiomiatic' way to code type inequality in haskell? If not, what are the problems with it?

Comment: i think you are missing a `)` in your type declaration for `g`.  Have you tried `g (2 :: Int) (3 :: Int)` ?

Comment: Oops, you are right, I keep forgetting the ambiguity for integer literals. I just tried `g 'a' "b"` and it works. Are there any  problems with the code that I wrote (I'm new to advanced haskell).

Comment: You don't need `IncoherentInstances`. `OverlappingInstances` is enough.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what kind of problem needs that kind of restriction?

Comment: For now, no problem, I'm just curious regarding how well some C++ features translate to haskell. In C++ these kind of things can be more useful though, since they can be used to prevent implicit type cast, which haskell almost never does.

Comment: Haskell actually *never* does a typecast.

Caveat: I'm not sure if I know enough Haskell to say that's always true, but I'm not aware of the language allowing typecasts, only that in GHC various `unsafe*` functions will let you do things like cast a float to a double to a pointer. The result will be nonsense, but that'll be your fault, and it's not so much a cast as telling the compiler to break all of its rules as you say, "Trust me, I know what I'm doing." The compiler will be suspicious of your motivations but believe you.

Comment: [I asked a potentially related question some months ago and got good answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273235/can-gadts-be-used-to-prove-type-inequalities-in-ghc).

Comment: @AaronFriel - I am not sure if this counts as a typecast, but features like OverloadedStrings cause implicit cast of literals. Also, there can be implicit cast of number literals to either int or integer. Maybe cast is not the right word here, but what I am saying is that just the literal itself doesn't always have the same type.

Comment: Cast is definitely the wrong word, but yes, literals are overloaded. But there are no typecasts or implicit conversions between types. `5 :: Integer` will always, always be an `Integer`. And `"Hello!" :: ByteString` won't ever suddenly become not a `ByteString` merely by how you use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [new](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commit/569b26526403df4d88fe2a6d64c7dade09d003ad) [features](https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2012/12/22/ordered-overlapping-type-family-instances/)  being added to GHC, you'll be able to write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, PolyKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

type family Equal (a :: k) (b :: k) :: Bool
type instance where
   Equal a a = True
   Equal a b = False
```

Comment: The syntax they ultimately chose was different. Now you'd write `type family Equal (a :: k) (b :: k) :: Bool where { Equal a a = 'True; Equal a b = 'False }`. The braces, of course, wouldn't be necessary if I could write a multi-line comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it is done in the [HList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.2.3) library

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, 
    MultiParamTypeClasses, 
    FunctionalDependencies, 
    UndecidableInstances ,
    IncoherentInstances
 #-}

data HTrue; data HFalse;

class TypeCast a b | a -> b
instance TypeCast a a

class TypeEq a b c | a b -> c
instance TypeEq x x HTrue
instance (TypeCast HFalse b) => TypeEq x y b
-- instance TypeEq x y HFalse -- would violate functional dependency
```

You can fully infer type equality now:

```
typeEq :: TypeEq a b c => a -> b -> c
typeEq _ _ = undefined
```

Note that `typeEq 0 1 == HFalse` since `0 :: Num a => a` and `1 :: Num b => b`.

Comment: Note that until the new features defined in the other answer are rolled out, this is basically _the_ way to do it.