# Is it possible to write fmap for this data type involving a type family?

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families

Given the following type family (supposed to reflect the isomorphism A×1 ≅ A)

```
type family P (x :: *) (a :: *) :: * where
  P x () = x
  P x a  = (x, a)
```

and data type defined in terms thereof

```
data T a = T Integer (P (T a) a)
```

is it possible by some type hackery to write a `Functor` instance for the latter?

```
instance Functor T where
  fmap f = undefined  -- ??
```

Intuitively, it's obvious what to do depending on the type of `f`, but I don't know how to express it in Haskell.

Comment: My gut says it shouldn't be possible since it would need to violate parametricity.

Answer (score 12):

I tend to reason about these kind higher kind programs using Agda.

The problem here is that you want to pattern match on `*` (`Set` in Agda), violate parametericity, as mentioned in the comment. That is not good, so you cannot just do it. You have to provide witness. I.e. following is not possible

```
P : Set → Set → Set
P Unit b = b
P a b = a × b
```

You can overcome the limitiation by using aux type:

```
P : Aux → Set → Set
P auxunit b     = b
P (auxpair a) b = a × b
```

Or in Haskell:

```
data Aux x a = AuxUnit x | AuxPair x a

type family P (x :: Aux * *) :: * where
  P (AuxUnit x) = x
  P (AuxPair x a) = (x, a)
```

But doing so you'll have problems expressing `T`, as you need to pattern match on its parameter again, to select right `Aux` constructor.

---

"Simple" solution, is to express `T a ~ Integer` when `a ~ ()`, and `T a ~ (Integer, a)` directly:

```
module fmap where

record Unit : Set where
  constructor tt

data ⊥ : Set where

data Nat : Set where
  zero : Nat
  suc : Nat → Nat

data _≡_ {ℓ} {a : Set ℓ} : a → a → Set ℓ where
  refl : {x : a} → x ≡ x

¬_ : ∀ {ℓ} → Set ℓ → Set ℓ
¬ x = x → ⊥

-- GADTs
data T : Set → Set1 where
  tunit : Nat → T Unit
  tpair : (a : Set) → ¬ (a ≡ Unit) → a → T a

test : T Unit → Nat
test (tunit x) = x
test (tpair .Unit contra _) with contra refl
test (tpair .Unit contra x) | ()
```

You can try to encode this in Haskell to.

You can express it using e.g. ['idiomatic' Haskell type inequality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749756/idiomatic-haskell-type-inequality)

I'll leave the Haskell version as an exercise :)

---

*Hmm* or did you meant by `data T a = T Integer (P (T a) a)`:

```
T () ~ Integer × (P (T ()) ())
     ~ Integer × (T ())
     ~ Integer × Integer × ... -- infinite list of integers?

-- a /= ()
T a ~ Integer × (P (T a) a)
    ~ Integer × (T a × a) ~ Integer × T a × a
    ~ Integer × Integer × ... × a × a
```

Those are easier to encode directly as well.