# Using type-inequality within type-level programming in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, gadt, type-level-computation, data-kinds

I am trying to do some advanced type-level programming; the example is a reduced version of my original program.

I have a representation of (Haskell) types. In this example I only cover function types, basic types and type variables.

The representation `Type t` is parameterized by one type variable `t` to also allow a differentiation on the type-level. To achieve this, I am mainly using GADTs. Different types and type variables are differentiated by using type-level literals, thus the `KnownSymbol` constraint and the use of `Proxy`s.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeOperators, DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies, PolyKinds #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Type.Equality

data Type :: TypeKind -> * where
  TypeFun    :: Type a -> Type b -> Type (a :-> b)
  Type       :: KnownSymbol t => Proxy t -> Type (Ty t)
  TypeVar    :: KnownSymbol t => Proxy t -> Type (TyVar t)
```

I have also restricted the kind of `t` to be of kind `TypeKind` by using the DataKinds and KindSignatures extensions and defining the `TypeKind` data-type:

```
data TypeKind =
    Ty Symbol
  | TyVar Symbol
  | (:->) TypeKind TypeKind
```

Now I want to implement substitutions of type variables, i.e. substituting, within a type `t`, every variable `x` that is equal to a type variable `y`, with type `t'`. The substitution must be implemented on the representation, as well as on the type-level. For the latter, we need TypeFamilies:

```
type family Subst (t :: TypeKind) (y :: Symbol) (t' :: TypeKind) :: TypeKind where
  Subst (Ty t) y t'    = Ty t
  Subst (a :-> b) y t' = Subst a y t' :-> Subst b y t'
  Subst (TyVar x) y t' = IfThenElse (x == y) t' (TyVar x)
```

The type variables are the interesting part, because we check for the equality of the symbols `x` and `y` on the type-level. For this, we also need a (poly-kinded) type family that allows us to choose between two results:

```
type family IfThenElse (b :: Bool) (x :: k) (y :: k) :: k where
  IfThenElse True  x y = x
  IfThenElse False x y = y
```

Unfortunately, this does not compile yet, which might be the first indicator of my problem:

```
Nested type family application
  in the type family application: IfThenElse (x == y) t' ('TyVar x)
(Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)
In the equations for closed type family ‘Subst’
In the type family declaration for ‘Subst’
```

Enabling the UndecidableInstances extension works, though, so we continue to define a function `subst` that works on the value-level:

```
subst :: (KnownSymbol y) => Type t -> Proxy (y :: Symbol) -> Type t' -> Type (Subst t y t')
subst (TypeFun a b) y t = TypeFun (subst a y t) (subst b y t)
subst t@(Type _) _ _    = t
subst t@(TypeVar x) y t'
  | Just Refl <- sameSymbol x y = t'
  | otherwise                   = t
```

This code works perfectly, except for the last line which produces the following compilation error:

```
Could not deduce (IfThenElse
                    (GHC.TypeLits.EqSymbol t1 y) t' ('TyVar t1)
                  ~ 'TyVar t1)
from the context (t ~ 'TyVar t1, KnownSymbol t1)
  bound by a pattern with constructor
             TypeVar :: forall (t :: Symbol).
                        KnownSymbol t =>
                        Proxy t -> Type ('TyVar t),
           in an equation for ‘subst’
  at Type.hs:29:10-18
Expected type: Type (Subst t y t')
  Actual type: Type t
Relevant bindings include
  t' :: Type t' (bound at Type.hs:29:23)
  y :: Proxy y (bound at Type.hs:29:21)
  x :: Proxy t1 (bound at Type.hs:29:18)
  subst :: Type t -> Proxy y -> Type t' -> Type (Subst t y t')
    (bound at Type.hs:27:1)
In the expression: t
In an equation for ‘subst’:
    subst t@(TypeVar x) y t'
      | Just Refl <- sameSymbol x y = t'
      | otherwise = t
```

I guess that the problem is that I cannot prove the inequality of the types of the two symbols `x` and `y`, and would need some kind of type-inequality witness. Is this possible? Or is there another, better way to achieve my goal?
I do not know to which extent the questions ['idiomatic' Haskell type inequality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749756/idiomatic-haskell-type-inequality) and [Can GADTs be used to prove type inequalities in GHC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273235/can-gadts-be-used-to-prove-type-inequalities-in-ghc) already answer my question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe this question can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749756/idiomatic-haskell-type-inequality

Comment: I guess you need a lemma `Either ((x==y) :~: True) ((x==y) :~: False)`. I am not sure how that can be proved with GHC `TypeLits`, nor if it is provable at all without `unsafe` stuff...

Comment: FYI, `UndecidableInstances` is usually necessary when you're trying to do non-trivial things with type families. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As chi said in the comments, what you need is `Either ((x==y) :~: True) ((x==y) :~: False)`. Unfortunately, type literals are partly broken currently, and this is one of the things we can only do with `unsafeCoerce` (a morally acceptable use though).

```
sameSymbol' ::
  (KnownSymbol s, KnownSymbol s') =>
  Proxy s -> Proxy s'
  -> Either ((s == s') :~: True) ((s == s') :~: False)
sameSymbol' s s' = case sameSymbol s s' of
  Just Refl -> Left Refl
  Nothing   -> Right (unsafeCoerce Refl)

subst :: (KnownSymbol y) => Type t -> Proxy (y :: Symbol) -> Type t' -> Type (Subst t y t')
subst (TypeFun a b) y t = TypeFun (subst a y t) (subst b y t)
subst t@(Type _) _ _    = t
subst t@(TypeVar x) y t' = case sameSymbol' x y of
  Left  Refl -> t'
  Right Refl -> t
```

On another note, if you don't mind some Template Haskell, the [`singletons`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) library can derive your definitions (and more):

```
{-# language GADTs, TypeOperators, DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeFamilies, PolyKinds #-}
{-# language UndecidableInstances, ScopedTypeVariables, TemplateHaskell, FlexibleContexts #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Singletons.TH
import Data.Singletons.Prelude

singletons([d|
  data Type sym
    = Ty sym
    | TyVar sym
    | Type sym :-> Type sym

  subst :: Eq sym => Type sym -> sym -> Type sym -> Type sym
  subst (Ty t) y t'    = Ty t
  subst (a :-> b) y t' = subst a y t' :-> subst b y t'
  subst (TyVar x) y t' = if x == y then t' else TyVar x        
  |])
```

This gives us type, kind and value level definitions for `Type` and `subst`. Examples:

```
-- some examples

-- type level
type T1 = Ty "a" :-> TyVar "b"
type T2 = Subst T1 "b" (Ty "c") -- this equals (Ty "a" :-> Ty "c")

-- value level

-- automatically create value-level representation of T1
t1  = sing :: Sing T1

-- or write it out by hand
t1' = STy (sing :: Sing "a") :%-> STyVar (sing :: Sing "b")

-- use value-level subst on t1:
t2 = sSubst t1 (sing :: Sing "b") (STy (sing :: Sing "c"))

-- or generate result from type-level representation
t2' = sing :: Sing (Subst T1 "b" (Ty "c"))

-- Convert singleton to non-singleton (and print it)
t3 :: Type String
t3 = fromSing t2 -- Ty "a" :-> Ty "c"
```